# Where should events be raised?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I'm not new to C#, but events is one of the most confusing topics I confront in the language.
one of the questions is: where should I assign the event handler to the event, or the question in other form: why most events are raised in the subscriber constructor? what does it mean?

like this example (taken from the book Mastering Visual C# )

```
public ReactorMonitor(Reactor myReactor)
{
myReactor.OnMeltdown +=
new Reactor.MeltdownHandler(DisplayMessage);
}
```

Comment: There is a difference between "subscribe" and "raise". You seem to be using the word "raise" incorrectly, as a synonym for "subscribe". Please clarify. As for the question of when or where to **subscribe** to events, that all depends on what your need is. Events are subscribed to when code needs to react to them. So, you always subscribe when you need to start reacting to the event. If you no longer need to react to the event, you unsubscribe. It's as simple as that. But each situation is different, making your question unanswerable without more context.

Comment: Subscribe event == listening, you start listening when you are born.  Raise event == talking, somebody else talks when they have some interesting to say.

Answer (score 3):

Raise = generate.  Events are not raised in the subscriber constructor.  The subscriber does not raise events at all.  The *event source* raises/generates events, and subscribers *subscribe to*, *receive*, and *handle* them.

Events in c# are nothing more than function pointers, i.e. a variable that contains a pointer (or list of pointers) to a function that matches a specific signature (typically `Action<object,EventArgs>`).  Or in the words of [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx):

> Delegates are like C++ function pointers but are type safe.

When you subscribe to an event, you are essentially saying "Store the address of my function.  When X happens, please call it (along with any other function whose address is stored)."

Thus the code

```
myReactor.OnMeltdown += Meldownhandler;
```

can be read as

```
objectThatRaisesEvents.FunctionPointer = MyHandler;
```

Notice that `MyHandler` is not followed by parentheses.  If it were `MyHandler()` that means you are invoking the function, the value of the expression `MyHandler()` is actually the return value of the function; `MyHandler` by itself doesn't invoke the function or return its value but instead returns the address of the handler itself. So the above line of code takes the *address* of `MyHandler` and stores it in a variable named `FunctionPointer`.

When the object that raises events invokes `FunctionPointer()` it is telling c# to obtain the address of the function stored in `FunctionPointer` and invoke it. 
 So it is really calling `MyHandler()` indirectly.  Thus these two lines do exactly the same thing:

```
objectThatRaisesEvents.FunctionPointer();
MyHandler();
```

Also notice the `+=` in your example.  In c# that is the equivalent of

```
objectThatRaisesEvents.FunctionPointer = 
objectThatRaisesEvents.FunctionPointer + MyHandler;
```

We typically use that syntax because there might be several handlers that subscribe to an event.  `+=` has the effect of appending our handler to the list. You could use `=` instead, but it would unsubscribe any existing handlers.

To answer your question-- when should you subscribe to events?  That is a very broad question, but typically

- In an ASP.NET web page, you'd subscribe during the `Init` event.
- In a Windows Form, you'd subscribe in the `InitializeComponent` method.

There are many other contexts of course... the bottom line is you should subscribe before you need to receive notifications of occurrences of the event.

Comment: _"So the above line of code takes the address of MyHandler and stores it in a variable named FunctionPointer"_ -- this is incorrect, and the rest of your description is a remarkable oversimplification of how delegates work. Your description of the `+=` syntax is also incorrect, as it relates to events.

Comment: IMO it is a simplification, but not an oversimplification, for the benefit of the OP.  Clearly you are more advanced.  Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Nice explanation on event-handling and delegates.

Answer (score 0):

The event is one of the standard features of .NET Framework built using delegate model implementing the Observer design pattern.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t(v=vs.110).aspx

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Where you subscribe to the event depends on the business rules, but most of the time you want to subscribe at the earliest possible moment which is usually the constructor of the class interested in the handling of the event.

When events should be raised on the other hand depends on what you are trying to communicate to the subscribers if it is a notification of the state change then you raise an event as soon as state is changed.

> An event is a message sent by an object to signal the occurrence of an
>   action. The action could be caused by user interaction, such as a
>   button click, or it could be raised by some other program logic, such
>   as changing a property’s value.